# HttpContext.Current is null during RegenerateIdentity

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-identity, identity, claims-based-identity, asp.net-identity-2

**Introduction:**

I'm building a custom implementation of Identity 2.0. By default the framework refreshes the user's identity every 30 minutes, creating a new `ClaimsIdentity`. Because I have some custom claims (that I set in my login methods) that I want to move over to the new `ClaimsIdentity` upon refresh, I came up with an approach that reads the current `ClaimsIdentity` from the `HttpContext` and returns it as the 'new' `ClaimsIdentity`. The problem is that `HttpContext.Current` is null when the identity is being refreshed, so I can't copy over my old claims to the new identity.

**The code:**

In my `Startup.cs` file I have this code that refreshes the user's identity every x minutes:

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
{
    AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
    Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
    {
        OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidatorExtensions.OnValidateIdentity(
            validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(0.5),
            regenerateIdentity: (manager, user) => manager.CreateIdentityAsync(user, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie))
    }
});
```

This `RegenerateIdentity` func calls this method in my `UserManager`:

```
public async override Task<ClaimsIdentity> CreateIdentityAsync(ApplicationUser user, string authenticationType)
{
    ClaimsIdentity claimsIdentity;
    if (HttpContext.Current != null && 
        HttpContext.Current.User != null && 
        HttpContext.Current.User.Identity != null && 
        HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        // Just return the existing ClaimsIdentity so we don't lose our custom claims
        claimsIdentity = (ClaimsIdentity)HttpContext.Current.User.Identity;

        // TODO refresh some claims from the database

        return claimsIdentity;
    }

    // Create a new ClaimsIdentity if none exists
    claimsIdentity = await ClaimsIdentityFactory.CreateAsync(this, user, authenticationType);
    claimsIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim(Constants.DefaultSecurityStampClaimType, await GetSecurityStampAsync(user.Id)));

    return claimsIdentity;
}
```

**The problem:**

The first time `CreateIdentityAsync` is called (when I log in), `HttpContext.Current` has a value, the identity is created, and all is well. The problem is: when `CreateIdentityAsync` is called again (because the identity is being refreshed) the `HttpContext.Current` is `null`. I don't understand why that is and I haven't been able to fix it.

**Theories:**

Some of my theories of why `HttpContext.Current` is `null`:

1. Something to do with async and the `HttpContext` not being transferred to the new thread? I tried building my own awaiter to copy over the `HttpContext.Current` but that didn't work.
2. The `HttpContext` is being actively destroyed by the framework to make sure it gets rid of everything? I haven't been able to find any code that does this so it seems unlikely.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

The cookie middleware runs at the authenticate stage in the IIS pipeline, which is prior to HttpContext or session state being made available. So you will need to work without it.